# Convergent sum of reciprocals?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let  n  denote a positive integer and let  $\sigma(n)$  denote the sum
of all divisors of  $n$, so that $\sigma(n)$ is larger than $n$ (for $n > 1$)
but not by much since it's bounded above by $c\  n\log \log n$ .

This invites comparison between situations in which the two are
interchanged.  As an example, consider the following:

Let $A$ be a subset of the positive integers.  Suppose that
            the sum of $1/n$ , for all $n$ in $A$ , converges.  Then the sum
            of 1/$\sigma(n)$  , over all $n$ in $A$, clearly converges as well.

*Is the converse true?*

Comment: When you say $s(n)$, do you not consider $n$ in the sum? If you do, consider using $\sigma(n)$. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RestrictedDivisorFunction.html .